# Não tenho permissão escrever em um diretório no laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel-5

Ola, estou tendo dificuldades para escrever em um diretório no laravel 5.6, eu criei o diretório no servidor e quando vou fazer o upload ele da esse erro:

```
unable to write in the "uploads/imagens/assinatura" directory
```

curioso que eu tenho um outro diretório "avatar" e uso a mesma forma para salvar imagens nos dois.
Eu consigo salvar no servidor interno, porem quando subo não consigo, segue os coódigos:

Código que salva em "assinatura" que diz que não tenho permissão:

```
        if($request->hasFile('ds_ass')){
            $destino = 'uploads/imagens/assinatura';
            $arquivo = $request->ds_ass;
            $nmArquivo = $id.'-'.date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y').'-'.date('i').'-'.date('s');
            $extensao = $arquivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $nomeArquivo = $nmArquivo.'.'.$extensao;
            $arquivo->move($destino,$nomeArquivo);
            $foto = $arquivo;
            $salvaFoto = new \App\Anexos;
            $salvaFoto->ID_CD_PESSOA = $id;
            $salvaFoto->DS_ARQUIVO = $nmArquivo;
            $salvaFoto->DS_EXTENSAO = $extensao;
            $salvaFoto->save();

            $fotoprof = $prof::find($idProf);
            $fotoprof->DS_ASSINATURA = $nomeArquivo;
            $fotoprof->save();
        }else{
              ...
```

Código que executa sem erros:

```
if($request->hasFile('ds_arquivo')){
                    $destino = 'uploads/imagens/avatar';
                    $arquivo = $request->ds_arquivo;
                    $nmArquivo = $id.'-'.date('d').'-'.date('m').'-'.date('Y').'-'.date('i').'-'.date('s') ;
                    $extensao = $arquivo->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $nomeArquivo = $nmArquivo.'.'.$extensao;
                    $arquivo->move($destino,$nomeArquivo);
                    $foto = $arquivo;
                    $salvaFoto = new \App\Anexos;
                    $salvaFoto->ID_CD_PESSOA = $id;
                    $salvaFoto->DS_ARQUIVO = $nmArquivo;
                    $salvaFoto->DS_EXTENSAO = $extensao;
                    $salvaFoto->save();

                    $fotoPessoa = \App\Pessoas::find($id);
                    $fotoPessoa->DS_FOTO = $nomeArquivo;
                    $fotoPessoa->save();
                }else{
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro de permissão:

### Se estiver no Linux

```
chmod -R 755 /diretorio/do/seu/projeto
chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /diretorio/do/seu/projeto
```

Geralmente os uploads são feitos nas pastas:

```
- storage/app
- public/
```

A função `$(whoami)` retorna o nome do seu usuário. Se por acaso for outro usuário como `www-data`, basta trocar no comando acima.

### Se estiver no Windows

Va até a pasta, botão direito, propriedades, desmarque **somente leitura** e tente novamente.

Você pode ir também na aba **Segurança** e tentar aplicar permissões a todos usuários de Leitura e Escrita, etc.

Comment: Consegui dando permissão através do servidor, obrigado.